# How to make Python Slack App listen to events?

Tags: python, slack-api

Could somebody please see why my code doesn't make Python Slack App react to any messages? I'm following the tutorial at https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/tree/main/tutorial and I got midway through step 4 when I realized my app doesn't react to any messages I send in the Slack workspace. Here's the code I have for the app:

```
import logging
from slack_bolt import App
from slack_sdk.web import WebClient
from onboarding_tutorial import OnboardingTutorial

app = App(token="first secret token here", signing_secret="second secret token here")
onboarding_tutorials_sent = {}


def start_onboarding(user_id: str, channel: str, client: WebClient):
    # Create a new onboarding tutorial.
    onboarding_tutorial = OnboardingTutorial(channel)

    # Get the onboarding message payload
    message = onboarding_tutorial.get_message_payload()

    # Post the onboarding message in Slack
    response = client.chat_postMessage(**message)

    # Capture the timestamp of the message we've just posted so
    # we can use it to update the message after a user
    # has completed an onboarding task.
    onboarding_tutorial.timestamp = response["ts"]

    # Store the message sent in onboarding_tutorials_sent
    if channel not in onboarding_tutorials_sent:
        onboarding_tutorials_sent[channel] = {}
    onboarding_tutorials_sent[channel][user_id] = onboarding_tutorial


# ================ Team Join Event =============== #
# When the user first joins a team, the type of the event will be 'team_join'.
# Here we'll link the onboarding_message callback to the 'team_join' event.

# Note: Bolt provides a WebClient instance as an argument to the listener function
# we've defined here, which we then use to access Slack Web API methods like conversations_open.
# For more info, checkout: https://slack.dev/bolt-python/concepts#message-listening


@app.event("team_join")
def onboarding_message(event, client):
    """Create and send an onboarding welcome message to new users. Save the
    time stamp of this message so we can update this message in the future.
    """
    # Get the id of the Slack user associated with the incoming event
    user_id = event.get("user", {}).get("id")

    # Open a DM with the new user.
    response = client.conversations_open(users=user_id)
    channel = response["channel"]["id"]

    # Post the onboarding message.
    start_onboarding(user_id, channel, client)


# ============= Reaction Added Events ============= #
# When a users adds an emoji reaction to the onboarding message,
# the type of the event will be 'reaction_added'.
# Here we'll link the update_emoji callback to the 'reaction_added' event.


@app.event("reaction_added")
def update_emoji(event, client):
    """Update the onboarding welcome message after receiving a "reaction_added"
    event from Slack. Update timestamp for welcome message as well.
    """
    # Get the ids of the Slack user and channel associated with the incoming event
    channel_id = event.get("item", {}).get("channel")
    user_id = event.get("user")

    if channel_id not in onboarding_tutorials_sent:
        return

    # Get the original tutorial sent.
    onboarding_tutorial = onboarding_tutorials_sent[channel_id][user_id]

    # Mark the reaction task as completed.
    onboarding_tutorial.reaction_task_completed = True

    # Get the new message payload
    message = onboarding_tutorial.get_message_payload()

    # Post the updated message in Slack
    updated_message = client.chat_update(**message)


# =============== Pin Added Events ================ #
# When a users pins a message the type of the event will be 'pin_added'.
# Here we'll link the update_pin callback to the 'pin_added' event.


@app.event("pin_added")
def update_pin(event, client):
    """Update the onboarding welcome message after receiving a "pin_added"
    event from Slack. Update timestamp for welcome message as well.
    """
    # Get the ids of the Slack user and channel associated with the incoming event
    channel_id = event.get("channel_id")
    user_id = event.get("user")

    # Get the original tutorial sent.
    onboarding_tutorial = onboarding_tutorials_sent[channel_id][user_id]

    # Mark the pin task as completed.
    onboarding_tutorial.pin_task_completed = True

    # Get the new message payload
    message = onboarding_tutorial.get_message_payload()

    # Post the updated message in Slack
    updated_message = client.chat_update(**message)


# ============== Message Events ============= #
# When a user sends a DM, the event type will be 'message'.
# Here we'll link the message callback to the 'message' event.


@app.event("message")
def message(event, client):
    """Display the onboarding welcome message after receiving any message
    """
    channel_id = event.get("channel")
    user_id = event.get("user")
    text = event.get("text")

    return start_onboarding(user_id, channel_id, client)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    app.start(3000)
```

And the command-line looks something like:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.388]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\sprogissd>cd pycharmprojects/pythonproject

C:\Users\sprogissd\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>python3 app.py
Bolt app is running! (development server)
```

I followed directions for adding permissions to the app in the tutorial, so those look exactly the same as the guidelines direct.

Comment: Hi, Step - 4 talks about subscription to slack events. Have you completed that step ?

Comment: https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/blob/main/tutorial/04-running-the-app.md#subscribe-to-events